# RabbitMQ / c# - hold only 100 running tasks at the same time

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, rabbitmq

I have a web page that on a button click - send multi `ajax` request to my controller. (parallel)

my controller function:

```
public string myFunction(string servername)
{
    return "respose for " + servername
}
```

My server can handle for example **only** 100 running taks (myFunction) at the same time - or it will crash.

RabbitMQ is running on my `localhost` server.

I want to send each funcion to "hold", and "unhold" it when I am running less then 100 tasks.

How can I do that with RabbitMQ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you have a problem with rabbitmq. I believe you have a problem with your application architecture.  There is nothing you can do with rabbit to solve the issue described in the question.

In a message-based architecture, the number of processors (n=100) is constant. It doesn't matter if they are on the same machine or multiple machines.  Each processor draws messages from the queue to ensure the workload is balanced.

The architecture described appears to have n=unknown processors, and creates a new processor for each new request. As-described, once n>100, the system blows up. This is what message architectures aim to prevent, by funneling requests to a queue, load can be evened out and managed.

Recommend solving your issue by looking at your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

send all requests through RabbitMQ, as soon as they come in to your controller.

set up your message consumer with a "prefetch" limit of 100 on the consumer. this will guarantee your consumer never has more than 100 messages it is currently processing.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html